# Possible to plot training and validation accuracy/loss for a model with three classes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I currently have a code where i am training one model with 3 classes. I was asked to show "the accuracy plot and loss plot for each class (totally 6 images)."
Is it possible for me to even do this? I currently only have one graph and this is my code for it:

```
def plot_costs(history,title):
  acc = history.history['accuracy']
  val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

  loss = history.history['loss']
  val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

  epochs_range = range(epochs)

  plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
  plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
  plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
  plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
  plt.legend(loc='lower right')
  plt.title(title+': Training and Validation Accuracy')

  plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
  plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
  plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
  plt.legend(loc='upper right')
  plt.title(title+': Training and Validation Loss')
  plt.show()


  ####### plot costs of each model
plot_costs(history,'Model')
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such concept as "Loss Curve for a particular class" or "Accuracy Plot for a particular class". Both the concepts are strictly limited to the model as a whole and not for each individual class.

Albeit, camouflage can be deduced as you can go for the "One-Vs-Rest" classifier using NN i.e. for each class, make a binary classifier with '1' representing that the image is of that particular class and '0' representing for the other 2 classes. This way, each of your binary classifiers is classifying each of the classes and now the above plots will stand true( kind-of ) for each of the classes.